# jQuery function if else - too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a basic function which is making a change to cell colors in a table.

I am getting values from a Slider and trying to color cells in a table as if they were tracking the slider. It is half working but does not keep up with the slider or is too fast.

To me it seems that myFunction() is executing more than once per step of the slider whereas it should only fire when the slider value changes...

Here's the code:

```
var p =0;

function myFunction()
{
 var SliderValue = $('#slider-step').val();


 var k = Math.floor(SliderValue/10);


 if (p == k) {
             $('.grid').find('tr:first td:nth-child(' + k + ')').css("background-color", "#F0B4F8");

             console.log("SliderValue--->" +  SliderValue + "   k = " + k + "    p = " + p);

            p = 0;

            } 

            else {
                 $('.grid').find('tr:first td:nth-child(' + k + ')').css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

         console.log("SliderValue--->" +  SliderValue + "   k = " + k + "    p = " + p);

         p = k;

         }           


}
```

CSS:

```
#grid, #grid td {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: yellow;

}

#grid td {
width: 25px;
height: 10px;
}

#grid td, th {
border-left: solid 3px black;
}
```

HTML: Table:

```
<table class="grid" id="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

HTML: Slider:

```
 <label for="slider-step">
        Position
        </label>
        <input type="range" name="slider-step" id="slider-step" value="0" min="0"
        max="100" step="6.4" class="ui-hidden-accessible" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Comment: What is calling `myFunction()`?

Comment: a change on the input is changing it...

Comment: try calling the function onMouseUp() instead of onChange().  That way only the final value is taken into the calculation (as opposed all the values between your starting and final values).  Assuming you have a slider that it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also if you could post a JSfiddle, you'd get more people to help you faster (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: onMouseUp() didn't do anything... but I'll try and get a JSfiddle example posted shortly. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LVawj/

Comment: What is the purpose of `step="6.4"` in the slider? It doesn't match the `Math.floor(SliderValue/10)` in the function

Comment: @CDspace. The jsfiddle example you have shown is what I'm getting (although I my jsfiddle doesn't work yet, not sure why). The step 6.4 is a leftover and was just a rough guess to move the slider (which doesn't have 100% width in Codiqa) to match the table cells.

Comment: @user1203605 on the fiddle check the setttings on the left, on the `6.4` try changing it to `10` and see if that gets closer to what you want, then adjust the table or slider width as appropriate

Comment: @CDspace: Thanks. The background color is yellow, so that I can see the 2 colors in the if/else section. Basically, I want to color the cell that 'matches' the slider but go back to white if the slider has moved on. Like covering my tracks, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you on the right track. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMkHA/2/)

First notice on the fiddle the slider step is `10`, to match the division by 10 in the code. Then I've changed it to use `p` to store the last value of the slider. This allows for comparison to the current value, and you can color it appropriately as it slides up or down.

```
var p =0;

function myFunction()
{
    var SliderValue = $('#slider-step').val();
    var k = Math.floor(SliderValue/10);

    // if the value is decreasing
    if (p >= k) {
        $('.grid').find('tr:first td:nth-child(' + k + ')').css("background-color", "#F0B4F8");
        console.log("SliderValue--->" +  SliderValue + "   k = " + k + "    p = " + p);
    // otherwise it's increasing
    } else {
        $('.grid').find('tr:first td:nth-child(' + k + ')').css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        console.log("SliderValue--->" +  SliderValue + "   k = " + k + "    p = " + p);
    }           
    // save value for comparison next time
    p = k;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, closer but the pinkish color should only be in one cell and 'follow' the slider. Otherwise, the previously colored pinkish cell should go back to white.

Comment: I've modified http://jsfiddle.net/BMkHA/2/ but the value of p always seems to be 1 behind or ahead of k, so the styling change only works on the first cell. It seems to me that the logic should work...

Comment: This was the best answer (even though others have been removed by their authors) and with a few extra changes I got what I needed. Thanks to CDspace

Comment: some experimentation with the math seems to be in order (outside the scope of this question), but it appears it's closer to what you wanted, glad to help